# How to make a form with just one input tag but multiple input fields with the use of map, keys and id

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, react-hooks, array.prototype.map

I created a form using this code using useState. But the issue is i want to make a code with lesser line and i want to create it with the use of keys and ids that uses only one single input tag in the code instead of multiple input tags. the code is mentioned below:

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from "react";
function App() {

 const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState([
  {
    name:'',
    email:'',
    username:'',
    password:'',
    confirm:'',
    mobile:''
 }
])



 const handelFormChange = (index, event) => {
  let data = [...inputFields]
  data[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
  setInputFields(data);
}


 const submit = (e) => { 
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(inputFields)
} 


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form className="bg-light" onSubmit={submit}>
        {/* <div className="form-group"> */}
        {inputFields.map((input, index) => {
        return(
        <div key={index} className="form-group"> 
          <label className="font-weight-regular"> Name </label>
          <input type="name" name='name' required value={input.name} onChange={event => handelFormChange(index,event)}></input>

          <label className="font-weight-regular"> Email </label>
          <input type="text" name='email' required value={input.email} onChange={event => handelFormChange(index,event)}></input>

          <label className="font-weight-regular"> Username </label>
          <input type="text" name='username' required value={input.username} onChange={event => handelFormChange(index,event)}></input>

          <label className="font-weight-regular"> Password </label>
          <input type="password" name='password' required value={input.password} onChange={event => handelFormChange(index,event)}></input>

          <label className="font-weight-regular"> Confirm Password </label>
          <input type="password" name='confirm' required value={input.confirm} onChange={event => handelFormChange(index,event)}></input>

          <label className="font-weight-regular"> Mobile Number </label>
          <input type="text" name='mobile' required value={input.mobile} onChange={event => handelFormChange(index,event)}></input>
        </div>
        )
        })}

        <button onClick={submit}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

So i tried to mention the make a form and i am a fresher in this field so i dont know how to make a form with single input field but i have the requirement of this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use a single input field to create a form with multiple inputs by using the 'name' attribute on the input field. The name attribute allows you to identify which input field the data is coming from when the form is submitted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).